# Clone entry in expressionengine with safecracker

Tags: expressionengine, safecracker

I have an expressionengine template for frontend users using safecracker to create entries.  ex: http://domain.com/index.php/create. After user creates an entry, the entry can be edited by going to http://domain.com/index.php/create/my_entry where my_entry is the entry user created. My question is can i provide the user an option to clone an entry. What is the best way to clone. I can't think of an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you could try creating a new template - say, `/index.php/clone/` - that you'd link to with the url_title of the entry to be cloned after it (e.g., `/index.php/clone/my_entry`). Then use a `channel:entries` tag with `url_title="{segment_2}"` to get the values of all the existing entry's fields, and nest an `{exp:safecracker}` tag inside of it?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" url_title="{segment_2}"}

    {exp:safecracker channel="my_channel"}
        <input name="title" type="text" value="{title} /> 
        <input name="my_custom_field" type="text" value="{my_custom_field}" /> 
        ... etc ...
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    {/exp:safecracker}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Worth a shot anyway.